# Prevent the camera from leaving the terrain

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The camera moves behind the `Before` - this is the `GameObject`.

```
public Transform Before, Camera;
public static volatile bool IsMove = false;
private float Speed = 0f;
private void FixedUpdate() {
    Speed = Rb.velocity.magnitude / 0.5f;
    IsMove = 1 > Speed;
    Camera.position = Vector3.Lerp(Camera.position, Before.position, (Speed <= 0 ? 11 : Speed) * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
}
```

Everything works fine, except that I can't figure out how to calculate that the camera has approached the boundary of the tirrane and there is no need to move it any further?

**UPD:**
I tried to do it like this:

```
if (!Physics.Raycast(cam.ViewportPointToRay(new Vector3(1, 0, 0)), cam.farClipPlane, terrainLayer)) {
    camera.position = new Vector3(oldPosition.x, camera.position.y, oldPosition.z);
    print("Right");
} else if (!Physics.Raycast(cam.ViewportPointToRay(new Vector3(0, 1, 0)), cam.farClipPlane, terrainLayer)) {
    camera.position = new Vector3(oldPosition.x, camera.position.y, oldPosition.z);
    print("Left");
}
```

But it was possible, as you can see, only 2 sides, but with the upper and lower parts, it will not work out in any way.

I need the camera to move the object only if it can be moved.

That is, if we move the object to the right side:

[image]

Then we can move along the `y` axis, if we have not reached the end point `y`.
It needs to work automatically.

Comment: your original question is _prevent the camera from leaving the terrain_. If you need the camera to move along the terrian's border when it is close to the edge, I think this is more complex and depends on a specific situation. Usually the movement of camera is not orthogonal to the terrain, are you sure the image is the real situation?

Comment: @shingo, I showed this for an example, in order to understand that I reached the right, you can only move up, left and down (more precisely, left, forward, back), well, in general, I think you understand the essence.
How can this be done? Already exhausted.

Answer (score 1):

A simple idea, do raycast on each corner of the camera with the terrain, if failed, reject the movement.

```
Camera cam;
Transform camera;
```

```
var oldPosition = cameraTransform.position;
cameraTransform.position = newPosition;

int terrainLayer = LayerMask.GetMask("Terrain");

if (!Physics.Raycast(cam.ViewportPointToRay(new Vector3(0, 0, 0)), cam.farClipPlane, terrainLayer))
    camera.position = oldPosition ;
else if (!Physics.Raycast(cam.ViewportPointToRay(new Vector3(0, 1, 0)), cam.farClipPlane, terrainLayer))
    camera.position = oldPosition ;
else if (!Physics.Raycast(cam.ViewportPointToRay(new Vector3(1, 0, 0)), cam.farClipPlane, terrainLayer))
    camera.position = oldPosition ;
else if (!Physics.Raycast(cam.ViewportPointToRay(new Vector3(1, 1, 0)), cam.farClipPlane, terrainLayer))
    camera.position = oldPosition ;
```

Comment: Does not work... working example is it possible?

Comment: What do you mean "not work"? Please elaborate it.

Comment: Well, my camera object is a transform, not `Camera`. This is firstly, secondly, I tried to add a `Camera` and do `Physics.Raycast(camera.ViewportPointToRay(new Vector3(0, 0, 0)), camera.farClipPlane, 12);` but nothing comes out, always `False` from whichever side it comes up.

Comment: I made some changes, use `cam` for a Camera. The last argument of Raycast is a layermask, you can use LayerMask class, or `1<<12` if the terrian is on layer 12.

Comment: Please, tell me what needs to be done. In order to have a little visibility behind the map, is there such a possibility?

Comment: You may shrink the area, eg: `(0.1, 0.9)`

Comment: Something did not get it, where to write these values?

Comment: The 4 Vector3 above, `new Vector3(0, 1, 0)` is at the top-left of the screen, if you change it to `new Vector3(0.1, 1, 0)`, the camera may go left a bit further. You can try different values to check the result.

Comment: There is a problem, I didn’t understand right away, but it lies in the fact that the whole camera stops, and it shouldn’t be like that. It is necessary if there is an opportunity to move, it should move, that is, rested to the right, if it has not yet rested up or down, then you can move along `y`. Already exhausted, I just can not understand these moments. Is it possible to do this at all?

Comment: tried to do something like this: `float x = camera.position.x; if (x <= oldPosition.x){x = oldPosition.x;} Vector3 vec = new Vector3(x, oldPosition.y, camera.position.z); camera.position = vec;` - nothing works ( How can these sides be calculated? (

Comment: You may try `localPosition` or `Transform.Tranlate`.

Comment: Can you help make this moment happen? I can't deal with this

Comment: Updated the question, look plz, otherwise we apparently misunderstood each other.

Answer (score 0):

Add a new answer to answer the updated example.

Add a helper method to simplify the code.

```
bool Raycast(float u, float v)
{
    return Physics.Raycast(cam.ViewportPointToRay(new Vector3(u, v, 0)), cam.farClipPlane, terrainLayer);
}
```

Still cast rays on the 4 corners.

```
int flag = 0;
if(Raycast(0, 1))
    flag |= 8;
if(Raycast(0, 1))
    flag |= 4;
if(Raycast(0, 1))
    flag |= 2;
if(Raycast(0, 1))
    flag |= 1;
```

Now we check which edge goes outside the rectangle, then don't move the camera towards that direction.

```
var delta = newPosition - oldPosition;
if(flag > 0)
{
   switch(flag)
   {
       case 5: //left
       case 9: //right
           delta.x = 0f;
           break;
       case 3: //up
       case 10: //down
           delta.y = 0f;
           break;
       default: //more than 1 edge
           delta.x = delta.y = 0f;
           break;
   }
   camera.position = oldPosition + delta;
}
```

Comment: Nothing comes out in any way, I have already tried everything and everything. It's not `x` and `y`, but `x` and `z`, I have `3D`. Is it really possible to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it like this:

```
if (!Physics.Raycast(cam.ViewportPointToRay(new Vector3(1, 1, 0)), cam.farClipPlane, terrainLayer)) {
    float x = Сamera.position.x;
    if (x <= oldPosition.x) {
        x = oldPosition.x;
    }
    Сamera.position = new Vector3(x, oldPosition.y, oldPosition.z);
} else if (!Physics.Raycast(cam.ViewportPointToRay(new Vector3(0, 0, 0)), cam.farClipPlane, terrainLayer)) {
    float x = Сamera.position.x;
    if (x >= oldPosition.x) {
        x = oldPosition.x;
    }
    Сamera.position = new Vector3(x, oldPosition.y, oldPosition.z);
}
if (!Physics.Raycast(cam.ViewportPointToRay(new Vector3(1, 0, 0)), cam.farClipPlane, terrainLayer)) {
    Сamera.position = new Vector3(oldPosition.x, oldPosition.y, Сamera.position.z);
} else if (!Physics.Raycast(cam.ViewportPointToRay(new Vector3(0, 1, 0)), cam.farClipPlane, terrainLayer)) {
    Сamera.position = new Vector3(oldPosition.x, oldPosition.y, Сamera.position.z);
}
```

It only works a little crookedly, sometimes there is a light behind the `Terrain`, but this is sometimes, perhaps because the speed of the object is too high and it breaks through because of this.
Or maybe not, I don't even know what it is yet.
I just don't know how else to do it.
I would be glad of any help, if there is a better and more reliable option, so that the camera goes strictly along the `Terrain` and does not go anywhere further.

Comment: In short, this also does not work correctly ...